# Converse of the criterion of the convergence of a Series in $\mathbb R$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

If a series is convergent,then the sequence of its partial sum may not be convergent , is it true ?
**For the convergence of the series we know if the sequence of partial sum converges then the series converges**, but does the converse hold ?.

Any insight..

Comment: A series is convergent if its partial sums converge; So if a series is convergent, then its partial sums must converge by definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is the **definition** of convergence of a series. It is really "if and only if".

Remember: a finite series is truly a sum, but an *infinite* series is not a sum--it is a limit, if it exists. We use summation notation for it, but don't make the mistake of thinking that you are adding up an infinite number of terms. You aren't. Rather, you're taking a limit of actual sums.

Comment: One more question I have , if we sum the even terms of the series,and construct the partial sum $\S_n$, where n is even , then is it true that the convergence of $\S_n$will imply the convergence of the series ? I think not . As the convergence of a subsequence of sequence doesn't imply its convergence, Right ?

Comment: Do you mean the sum of the first $2n$ terms $a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_{2n}$, or the sum of the first $n$ even terms $a_2+a_4+\cdots+a_{2n}$?

Comment: The second one, n even terms.

Comment: No. Then the odd terms could be anything, so the series needn't converge. For example, what if the even terms are all $0$ and the odd terms are all $1$?

Comment: Oh ! I get it ,will you please look at my explanation in my comments, am I right ?

Comment: Yes, your statement in the comment is correct. Convergence of a subsequence does not imply convergence of the original sequence (nor does it preclude it--no conclusion can be drawn). **Note:** your "even terms only" is not a partial sum. A partial sum is defined to be the sum of a finite number of consecutive initial terms (you can't skip any terms).

Comment: Thanks for time sir..